# How to know when the user touches the OK button of the last StoreKit alert "Thank you. Your purchase was successful"?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have integrated "In App Purchase" in a game to let the user unlock more levels. Everything works fine, but I have a little problem with the last alert "Thank You. Your purchase was successful. [OK]". My program gets informed that the transaction was successfully completed before this last alert pops up and so my game starts running again - then the alert comes up, annoying the user. I would like to wait with my game running until the user touches the "OK" button, but since it is an alert from StoreKit I have no idea when this happens or how I could catch it.

I don't want to create another dialog (this time my own, therefor under my control) below the alert, just asking for touching "OK" again - would be a bad user experience.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) set that storekit alert as delegate = yourclass.

2) Declare yourclass with the **UIAlertViewDelegate**, then use this method to intercept the alert:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

You can check the alert title/message to see if it's the correct alert:

```
if ([alertView.message isEqualToString:@"Thank you.. bla bla bla"]) {
    //something
}
```

Comment: How do you do #1 (get the storekit alert)? On iOS 8 (don't know about 7), the OS pops up that last alert after all delegate and observer calls are made, and I can't find a way to access the alert to set the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same question. I found that whenever the user touches "OK" to that "Thank you" message, `applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` is called, so maybe this could be a way.
I'd like to know if someone has a better way though..

Answer (score 1):

I think Irene in on the right path. I had this same problem and scoured the "Interwebs" to find an answer, and it seems that there is none.

For the purposes of your game, I would recommend pausing and resuming the game in response to your `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:` UIApplicationDelegate methods. Not only will this cause the game to be paused until the user dismisses the successful purchase alert, it will also pause the game when a text message is received, a phone call is received, or any other event causes the application to be interrupted.

While annoying in this case, adding automatic pausing and resuming of your game will add a very user-friendly feature that your users will appreciate.